# Get IIS Version & Dot Net Version from Web Requests

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a MVC Web Application installed on My IIS in Windows 10.
In Pen testing it was suggested that IIS Version & Dot Net Version are getting disclosed.

I have found a number of solutions to correct them however I want to myself check the IIS Version/ Dot Net Version revealed in Web Requests which i was unable to do in Google Chrome > Network Tab > XHR Requests

Is there any way I can check by sending a dummy request or any kind of command to my IIS Site to get the IIS Version and Dot Net Core Version like any PowerShell script or any DOS command or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Visit your site in chrome
2. Open Developer tools (F12 on windows)
3. Switch to the network tab
4. Click on any request on in the list.
5. Check the headers to see something like this (note powered by and server):

[image: Response headers]

Comment: Okay, i will try and let know my findings

Comment: + I can see Server in non XHR Requests but how to check dot net version

Comment: I want to see X-AspNet-Version Header

Comment: The headers in the list are the headers that are being sent. Try visiting your site, pressing F12 and then refreshing the page and checking the very first request.